# Basic if..elseif...else question in PHP

Tags: php

Sorry, just a very basic question on conditionals in PHP

```
If {}
elseif {}
else {}
```

If the `if` condition comes out to be true, will PHP still evaluate the `elseif` to see if that is true as well?

Comment: Try it and see? My money's on "No."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. (Basic answer for a basic question)

You can read about that in depth in the PHP Manual: [elseif/else if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php), the first example is like yours.

Comment: I think people just like @hakre for the completeness of his / her answers. :)

Answer (score 11):

Not, it won't.  It will just execute the `if` code, and then continue after the `else`.

In order to see it, you could check this:

```
if (true)
{
  echo "foo inside if"
}
else if (true)
{
  echo "foo inside else if"
}
else 
{
   echo "foo inside else";
}

echo "\nfoo after else"
```

The above code will print:

```
   foo inside if
   foo after else
```

and not

```
   foo inside if
   foo inside else if
   foo after else
```

Answer (score 5):

Nope!  Once a condition is met anywhere in an if/else block, PHP exits that block and moves on.  For example, in this code:

```
if ($a <= 3) {
  echo "small";
}
elseif ($a <= 6) {
  echo "medium";
}
else {
  echo "large";
}
```

... if `$a` is 2, it will echo "small" because `$a` is <= 3, but **not** "medium", even though `$a` is also <= 6.

If you **did** want PHP to check subsequent conditions, you'd use multiple if statements instead.  For example:

```
if ($b < 4) {
  echo "less than 4";
}
if ($b < 8) {
  echo "less than 8";
}
```

... would echo both "less than 4" and "less than 8" if `$b` were, say, 3.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already mentioned, no, it will not even test the `elseif` condition. This is also important for situations like the following:

```
$a = 1;

if ($a > 0) { }

else if (++$a > 0) { } // note the increment operator

else { }

echo $a; // produces 1
```

Any expressions that modify values as a byproduct of the condition test will not fire either.

Answer (score 3):

If the first `if` is true, the code will enter the `if` and then execute the code inside of there. Then it will exit past the `else` and continue on.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't. After executing the if code, it will continue execution after the else.

Answer (score 2):

Not the case. As soon as the condition you specify is met in a if query, php will stop going forward with the process and will contiue on to the code that appears after the if query has been ended.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't execute else if statements as the if condition becomes true 
This is general truth for if-else-if-else block in all languages

```
$a=1;
if($a==1){
echo "inside if";
}else if($a==2){
echo "inside else if";
}else{
echo "inside else";
}
```

It will have output as below:
inside if 
As the value of a is 1 it won't execute else if and else block

Hope it Helps!!!!